# Pandas not changing dtype when using describe()

Tags: python, pandas, methods, casting

This is probably related to my lack of understanding about programming.

If i do:

```
dict = {'A':[10.0, 9.10, 8.93, 9.5], 
        'B':[3.0, 7.45, 5.6, 10.3], 
        'C':[5.32, 4.30, 8.0, 9.8]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df['A'].describe()

Out:
count     4.000000
mean      9.382500
std       0.475981
min       8.930000
25%       9.057500
50%       9.300000
75%       9.625000
max      10.000000
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

If i try to change to integer type

```
df['A'] = df['A'].round(0).astype('int32')
df['A'].describe()

Out:
count     4.00000
mean      9.50000
std       0.57735
min       9.00000
25%       9.00000
50%       9.50000
75%      10.00000
max      10.00000
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Seems it hasn't changed. However:

```
df['A'].describe

Out:
<bound method NDFrame.describe of 
0    10
1     9
2     9
3    10
Name: A, dtype: int32>
```

The latter result can be confirmed by using df.dtypes.
What is happening here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df['A'].describe()` returns some statistics of teh column, including `mean`, `std`. Those are most likely non-integer. Therefore the dtype of that series is cast to `float64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`describe` is a method of the DataFrame object. To call a method, you have to use the brackets. Without brackets, it just gives you the method object itself, and not the result.

Also, if you want to convert the describe section to int format, you should write:

```
df['A'] = df['A']
df['A'].describe().astype(int)

result:
count     4
mean      9
std       0
min       8
25%       9
50%       9
75%       9
max      10
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

`describe()` method is primarily to generate descriptive statistics information.  you can refer [describe method doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html)

To check data type, you should use `dtypes`.

When you use `describe` method, it will not return as series or dataframe. It just type of `object` which does hold some data. You should use `()` to retrieve the data.

[image]